# Netbeans SFTP connection - Passive mode

Tags: netbeans

I use Netbeans and I want to grab a project using SFTP connection (port 22).

The connection test succedeed but when I want to grab files, it says

```
No files available for download. Try to check Passive mode in the remote connection
```

But I can't check **Passive Mode** in SFTP connection, I can in FTP but no FTP...

Anyway to config it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP in Netbeans 8.2 and 9.0 doesn't show the passive checkbox.

After some agony myself...

It may be that message is being returned because the default download and/or upload directory set in Netbeans doesn't exist.

To the extent it's not obvious, login with your favourite FTP client to the site you are trying to connect to and checkout the directory structure of the remote site.

If all else fails, try "" for the Upload directory and "/" for the download directory. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ty putting full path. Use command "pwd" instead of "/public_html"
directory.